# css position sticky not found

Tags: css, position

I'm trying to implement position sticky on my site but  I get  warning messages in cpanel editor that says

Expected(static | relative | absolute | fixed | inherit) but found '-webkit-sticky'
Expected(static | relative | absolute | fixed | inherit) but found 'sticky'

This is my script:

```
.advanced
{
position: -webkit-sticky; 
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

What could be the the problem?

Comment: Your cpanel editor is probably outdated and doesn't know this value. But it's valid and [compatible](https://caniuse.com/css-sticky) to most modern browsers

Comment: so unless I change my editor the script won't be executed?

Comment: Correct Luis. Even Visual Studio still tells me that `scroll-behavior: smooth;` isn't a valid CSS property, but it is. A lot of code editors have some form of this type of issue and you can't update it unfortunately.

Comment: Do these warning messages prevent you from actually saving the file?